# To find Possible values of combinations of a & b for $a^2 + b^2 = 576$ or any quadratic equation under certain restrictions.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, quadratics, quadratic-forms

Q: Find possible values of combination of a&b such that $a^2 + b^2 = 576$ or any other quadratic equation under certain restrictions. The sole purpose is to understand how can we do it:

CONDITION: Value of both a & b has to be under 576. a & b cannot be a decimal value , negative value (Like -7 or -16 etc)

1 solution will be 0,24. Now , we have to find all the possible combinations & I have been trying to do it like starting & checking all possible combinations. Like $10^2 + 11^2$ , No , $12^2 + 11^2$ , No. So , u see like that it is very time consuming. I’m unable to think or find a faster way to find all the possible values.

Comment: Maybe you should look into Pythagorean triples.

Comment: well, both $a,b$  must be divisible by $24.$

Comment: @WillJagy Prime factorisation will be 2*2*2*3

Comment: @Lelouch That only gives 1 solution , not all the other possible.

Comment: Search for sum of two squares theorem.  There are results on what numbers can be represented, how many representations there are, and how to find them.  It depends on the prime factorization of the right side number.  If it has a prime of the form $4k+3$ to an odd power it cannot be represented at all.  You can build the others from representations of the $4k+1$ primes.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yup , it gives 1 solution only,